# Fetching xml in React

Tags: xml, reactjs

Tryin to fetch a XML Document but only getting an empty object back. Code looks like this:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch("xml", {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/xml',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        })
    })
        .then(response => {
            response.text().then(text => {
                console.log(text)
            })
        })

}
```

i want to display the content of the xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving an opaque response, as the result of using the `no-cors` mode.

To make a request via JavaScript to the page that you've mentioned, you'll need to ensure that the page is served with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, specifying the origin of your React component.

Alternatively, you can reverse proxy the resource, and ensure that this header is set (or reverse proxy the resource from the same origin as that which you serve your React component). You may consider using something along the lines of [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) for this.

**Example:**

```
fetch("")
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => console.log(text));
```